# TypeScript 2.0 fails wth @types from symlinked node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig, typescript2.0

Long story short, our build process before firing "npm start" command creates symlink to node_modules folder in the root folder of the project taking it from some other place.

Our npm start command setup in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "tsc @App/Other/Gulp/preCompile.txt && gulp build",
...
  }
```

So it does run npm install, but because we symlinked the node_modules and npm detects all packages installed, it jumps into "tsc @App/Other/Gulp/preCompile.txt" but this fails, because compiler tries accessing files both from symlink local folder "node_modules" and original "node_modules", exact lines from log:

```
> tsc @App/Other/Gulp/preCompile.txt && gulp build
../../../../../../Resources/Development/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(17,21): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'angular'.
../../../../../../Resources/Development/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(18,21): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ng'.
node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(17,21): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'angular'.
node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(18,21): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ng'.
```

I have tried setting typeroots in tsconfig.json to "node_modules/@types" which is default value, but t did not help. Seems like it could by typescript 2.0 bug, as the original path is relative to the project root...

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: This appears to be a bug with current TypeScript version (2.0.3). I have reported it and it was tagged and assigned to a developer ( https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11107 ).